# How can I read a NinePatch image from "disk" and convert to a NinePatchDrawable?

Tags: android, nine-patch

I want to read several NinePatch images from SD or from assets, thus not compiled, and there are no constructors/factories I can find to do the job.  I've also tried the NinePatch tool source, but it uses internals of the image to do the job and doesn't use the Android classes...

Kenny.

Comment: You've seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510467/android-compiling-9-patch-files-to-be-used-outside-of-the-drawable-folder?

Answer (score 1):

- Load your ninepatch image into a Bitmap object (there is many ways to do that, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html).
- Load your chunk (created by 9patch software)
- Then, use `NinePatch (Bitmap bitmap, byte[] chunk, String srcName)` constructor in order to create your NinePatch object.